# Can Azure Migrate be used similarly to Flyway for schema migration?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration, database-schema, schema-migration

Our team's application is in early development and will be using our application for usage/testing purposes.  There'll be changes in our SQL schema that will require dealing with schema migrations.

While I know that Liquidbase and Flyway are good tools for schema migration, does [Azure migrate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-migrate/) allow for similar functionality between schema versions on the same database?  Or is it only reserved for migrate from one database engine to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Azure migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-services-overview) support the database and the schema migration:

- Databases: Assess on-premises databases and migrate them to Azure SQL
  Database or to SQL Managed Instance.

But I think you also could look at [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15). If your database is not very large and that's a better tools. It supports schema migration between same Server/database.

Ref this example: [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5455/using-the-data-migration-assistant-dma-tool-to-migrate-from-sql-server-to-azure-sql-database/#:~:text=Using%20the%20Data%20Migration%20Assistant%20%28DMA%29%20tool%20to,the%20Azure%20SQL%20database.%20...%20More%20items...%20](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5455/using-the-data-migration-assistant-dma-tool-to-migrate-from-sql-server-to-azure-sql-database/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20Data%20Migration%20Assistant%20%28DMA%29%20tool%20to,the%20Azure%20SQL%20database.%20...%20More%20items...%20)

Per my experience about Azure, there isn't a way to sync the schema. Azure migrate or DMA or DMS more focus on the schema/database migration, both can not meet your request.

HTH.

Comment: Seems that links only assume that you have a database on-premise that you want to migrate over to the cloud.  What I wanted was to supply an updated schema of our database and, through comparing the differences, update the Azure SQL Database as well as preventing data from being corrupted from the schema changes

Comment: @JosephWoolf, per my experience about Azure, there isn't a way to sync the schema. Azure migrate or DMA or DMS more focus on the schema/database migration, both can not meet  your request.

Comment: I understand.  Thank you anyway

Comment: @JosephWoolf You're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you, and have a nice day!

Comment: If you update your answer to better reflect what I was looking for, I'll accept your answer